# How to get start and end dat for week number in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate

In my iOS app, I have a week number and I need to get the start and end date for that week number.

I'm building an app with which the manager of a company can keep track of the worked hours of staff. These worked hours are processed per day in a custom `Registration` object. 
In this object, the date, begin time, end time and break time are stored and based on those values, the worked hours are calculated.

Then, all `Registration` objects are stored in a `WorkWeek` object, containing a week number and an array of registrations. `WorkWeek`'s are constructed based on weeknumbers and run from monday through sunday. In this `WorkWeek` object, the total worked hours, extra hours and wage are calculated.

Now obviously, I can't reliably calculate extra hours if a `Workweek` is not a full week that runs from monday through friday. This particularly occurs when the user chooses to get all registrations from a mont from my database. A month does not start on monday and does not end on sunday exactly four weeks later, so i'm dealing with unreliable week object.

**Wrapping up**

To make sure the information I display in my app is reliable, I need to determine whether a certain week (like week 1 or week 52) contains at least 7 days and, if not, I need to set a bool to FALSE which then triggers a notification to my user.

**How can I get the begin and end date of a week based on a weeknumer?**

Comment: What sort of week __doesn't__ have 7 days? I don't understand the question?

Comment: As stated in my description, The user can choose to display a certain month, e.g. January. 1 January is not monday, and 30 january is not sunday exactly 4 weeks later. Despite of that, all registrations my app receives, will still be processed as WorkWeek objects, to calculate hours per week and wage. The only problem is that if a workweek doesn't have 7 days, i can't reliably calculate extra hours, and thus need to know whether I have a full week or only a part. Does this clarify my question?

Comment: A practical example would be this month: 1st of January is Thursday and the last day is only four days later, Sunday the fourth. received Registrations would be processed in a workweek, but as the WorkWeek object does not contain 7 days, i can't reliably calculate extra hours and thus wage. All I need is a to know how to determine the first and last day of a week when a weeknumber is given. I can figure out the rest myself

Comment: You mean you want to know whether the first and last days of a week are in the same month?

Comment: No. All I need is a function / piece of code that, when I pass in a weeknumer (like week 1, or week 40), gives back the first and last day of that week. The entire story i wrote around it is to provide some context. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows how it could be done:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Start of week:
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comp.weekday = cal.firstWeekday;
comp.weekOfYear = 1; // <-- fill in your week number here
comp.year = 2015;    // <-- fill in your year here
NSDate *startOfWeek = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

// Add 6 days:
NSDate *endOfWeek = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:6 toDate:startOfWeek options:0];

// Show results:
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromDate:startOfWeek]);
NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromDate:endOfWeek]);
```

Some notes:

- `cal.firstWeekday` gives the locale dependent index of the first weekday, e.g.
  `2 = Monday` in Germany, or `1 = Sunday` in the U.S. Depending on your needs, 
  you can also use a constant value here.
- It might be necessary to set `cal.minimumDaysInFirstWeek`, compare
  [NSDateFormatter reports June 2, 2013 as being in week zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898019/nsdateformatter-reports-june-2-2013-as-being-in-week-zero).
- The `dateByAddingUnit:...` method is available in OS X 10.9 or later.
  Alternatively, use `dateByAddingComponents:...`.
- I have assumed that you use the Gregorian calendar, so that a week has 7 days.
  Alternatively, you can add one week and then subtract one day.

Comment: You're obviously not as lazy as I am :)

Comment: @Abizern: It depends :) But I find calendar calculations often interesting. In this case, the above code gave wrong results until I added `comp.weekday = cal.firstWeekday`.