# A bug with DateComponents?

Tags: swift, date

I have a simpel question:

```
func findWeekNumber(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    var newEventComponents = DateComponents()
    newEventComponents.day = day
    newEventComponents.month = month
    newEventComponents.year = year
    var newEventDate = calendar.date(from: newEventComponents)
    var newEventWeekNumber = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: newEventDate!)
    var weeknumber = newEventWeekNumber.weekOfYear!
    print("The date lies in week: \(weeknumber)")
}

findWeekNumber(day: 30, month: 12, year: 2020)
```

This prints 1, but it should be 53. What am I doing wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: tried to print it as Date , may be it enters 2021 as of timezone

Comment: I get `53` – but that depends on the `firstWeekday` and `minimumDaysInFirstWeek` properties of your calendar, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/16898019/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/34249588/1187415

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715711/nscalendar-nsdatecomponents-weekofyear-return-1-with-date-2014-12-31.

Comment: Try using an iso8601 calendar instance for the calculation.

Comment: iCal shows week 53 so when I use a locale calendar it should show the same...right? - Thanks for the posts Martin!

Comment: the firstWeekDay and minimumDaysInFirstWeek properties was set to 1 by default. That's strange but that explains it. But why are these not set to my locale calendar?